not connected variety in the Zariski topology

Let $V$ be a nonempty affine algebraic set. Prove that if $k[V]$ is the direct sum of two nonzero ideals then $V$ is connected in the Zariski topology. (A topological space is connected if it is not the union of two disjoint, proper, open subsets)

Let $R=k[\mathbb{A}^n]$ and $k[V]=k[\mathbb{A}^n]/\mathcal{I}(V)=\bar R=\bar I\oplus\bar J$. After some computation we obtain that $I+J=R$, $I\cap J=\mathcal{I}(V)$ and that $V=\mathcal{Z}(I)\sqcup\mathcal{Z}(J)$. So it remains to prove $\mathcal{Z}(I),\mathcal{Z}(J)$ are open.
Since I have not learnt about topology before I study the Zariski topology, so I am confused about "connected in the Zariski topology": which one is this Zariski topology based on, $\mathbb{A}^n$ or $V$?
If it is based on $V$ then $\mathcal{Z}(I),\mathcal{Z}(J)$ are clearly open since $V\setminus\mathcal{Z}(I)=\mathcal{Z}(J),V\setminus\mathcal{Z}(J)=\mathcal{Z}(I)$ are both closed.
If it were based on $\mathbb{A}^n$ I found no way to show that $\mathbb{A}^n\setminus\mathcal{Z}(I),\mathbb{A}^n\setminus\mathcal{Z}(I)$ were closed since I could not find them to be a union or an intersection of two closed sets.
The followings are some of my questions about this problem:
[1] Let $V$ be closed in $\mathbb{A}^n$ where $\mathbb{A}^n$ is equipped with the Zariski topology. If $U$ is closed in $\mathbb{A}^n$ and $U\subset V$ then is it necessary that $V-U$ is open in $\mathbb{A}^n$? (The converse is true: if $U$ is open in $\mathbb{A}^n$ and $U\subset V$ then $V-U=(\mathbb{A}^n-U)\cap V$ is closed.)
[2] What is the relation between the open sets in the subspace topology on $V$ and the ones in the initial topology  on $\mathbb{A}^n$? (The closed sets w.r.t. to the subspace topology in $V$ are just $C\cap V$ where $C$ is closed in $\mathbb{A}^n$.)
[3] Could you show me a counterexample in my initial question, i.e., is there any $V,I,J$ as described but $\mathcal{Z}(I)$ or $\mathcal{Z}(J)$ is not open in $\mathbb{A}^n$?

$\mathbb{A}^n$ is connected (even irreducible), so $Z(I)$ will almost never be open in $\mathbb{A}^n$, except for the trivial cases where $I=0$ or $I=k[x_1,...,x_n]$. The statement is about the sets being open in $V$.

@Mark Thanks for your answering. If $k$ is infinite then $\mathcal{I}(\mathbb{A}^n)=\langle0\rangle\in\mathbf{Spec},k[\mathbb{A}^n]$ so $\mathbb{A}^n$ is irreducible. If $k\cong\mathbb{F}q$ is finite, is it true that $\displaystyle\mathcal{I}(\mathbb{A}^n)=\left<\prod{i=1}^n\big(x_i^q-x_i\big)\right>$? And if so, is there any reference talking about how to show that $\mathcal{I}(\mathbb{A}^n)$ is a prime ideal?

Why do you need $k$ to be infinite for this statement to be true?

@Daniel Sorry, I do not know what do you mean, I have not mentioned that $k$ is infinite in my initial question. In the above comment I am just curious about whether $\displaystyle\mathcal{I}(\mathbb{A}^n)=\left<\prod_{i=1}^n\big(x_i^q-x_i\big)\right>$ is true or not if $k$ is finite.
